# Issues submitting app to Apple store

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to submit my iOS app to the Apple Store (tested on multiple devices, compiles and runs fine) but am getting the following errors:

**ERROR ITMS-90362:** "Invalid Info.plist value. The value for the key 'MinimumOSVersion' in bundle myapp.com/Frameworks/SwiftForms.framework is invalid. The minimum value is 8.0"

**ERROR ITMS-90209:** "Invalid Segment Alignment. The app binary at ' myapp.app/Frameworks/SwiftForms.framework.framework/SwiftForms' does not have proper segment alignment. Try rebuilding the app with latest Xcode version."

I am using xcode 6.4 and I have set my iOS Deployment Target to 8.0.  Any help appreciated!

Comment: Why not try to build and submit with Xcode 7? It says try rebuilding the app with latest Xcode version